# error Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return -> cloud funtion google

Tags: nodejs, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy tratando de implementar este ejemplo pero siempre obtengo el mismo error

```
function getAll(db) {

  var citiesRef = db.collection('cities');   
  var allCities = citiesRef.get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            return allCities;
         // console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });

   return allCities; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta muy raro tu código, ¿Quieres recuperar todos los documentos de la colección en una variable para después retornarlo?

En ese caso mejor haz esto:

```
  async function getAll(db) {return await db.collection('cities').get() }
```

¿Tiene sentido?
Utilizarias una función Asyncrona y le pondrias un await a la consulta. Esto te va a regresar el snapshot de cities y lo puedes utilizar en donde lo vayas a usar así:

```
const cities =  getAll(db)
```

Solo faltaria saber como lo quieres guardar,
esto te regresa el snapshot pero no cada objeto de cada ciudad, para eso, tienes que hacerle forEach a los documentos del snapshot e irlos metiendo a un array.

Comment: bueno esta repuesta me sirve, y pues encontre que solamente tenia que color un retunr